# Using Flexbox/Grid to Blur the background of an Image centered in a container in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I'm stumped. I want to create something like this: [image]

Where the background is the same image but blurred. The restrictions are that the image must be centered in the container

I have something like this:

```
<div className="image-container">
  <img className="image-to-show" url>
  <div className="image-bg"/>
</div>
```

My issue is the image-to-show has to be aligned in the middle. I have

```
.image-container{
 display:flex,
 align:center
}

img.image-to-show{
 width:60%
}
```

The problem is I can't align image-to-show to the center since the image-container has 3 divs so it will also take into consideration image-bg. How can I add the background blur to this and center the image in the container? I was thinking of adding the backgground image to the container but if I add blur ontop of that, the entire container gets blurred.

Comment: checkout this link, It seems to be helpful
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_blurred_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved, please take a look at the code snippet. For clear result, click on full page after running the snippet.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-image {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbDSiyg7FTcSl0C5Y1SNyXtIn6y5QZ_eUbvbmTwXeWJ2dXXl2ZiA&s");
  
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 
  
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
.bg-text {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbDSiyg7FTcSl0C5Y1SNyXtIn6y5QZ_eUbvbmTwXeWJ2dXXl2ZiA&s");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 500px 300px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image"></div>

<div class="bg-text">
  <h2>Blurred Background</h2>
  <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>
</div>
```